# How do I convince Agda's universe checker that what I'm doing is well-founded?

Tags: types, functional-programming, agda, dependent-type

I have a function that maps natural numbers to their corresponding Agda universe level.

```
level : Nat -> Level
level zero = lzero
level (suc l) = lsuc (level l)

Setn : (l : Nat) -> Set (level (suc l))
Setn l = Set (level l)
```

I use this function in the definition an inductive datatype in this manner:

```
data U l : Setn l where
  ...
  Lift : {l' : Nat} -> {l' <= l} -> U l' -> U l
```

Here, Agda complains that `Set (level l')` is not less than or equal to `Set (level l)`, which is clearly false, though I understand that Agda is not equipped to derive that `Set (level l') <= Set (level l)` from `l' <= l`. How do I hint to Agda's universe checker that this definition is indeed well-founded?

Comment: What are the other `...` things in `U`? The answer depends on that. If you don't put `(A : Set l)` inside any of the constructors, i.e. type formers in `U` only refer to types in `U`, then it's possible to drop `level` altogether.

Comment: I have [a post](http://effectfully.blogspot.com/2016/07/cumu.html) about this kind of thing. The trick there doesn't use naturals, but you can probably add them (and you might not need them at all).

Comment: @AndrásKovács unfortunately my constructors do take arguments that live in `Set l`.

Comment: @user3237465, thanks, your post looks great, and might actually replace my need for using naturals. Unfortunately (if I understand correctly), it doesn't seem possible to use this without disabling strict positivity, and I don't understand the potential consequences of doing that in the context of my project.

Comment: @NJay I think at some point Agda developers fixed that behavior where positivity was only tracked in parameters and not indices, so if you have a recent version of Agda, I suggest to copypaste the code from the post and check if `NO_POSITIVITY_CHECK` is still needed. No guarantees it's not, though.

Comment: There is another programming language Arend that supports this feature: https://arend-lang.github.io/documentation/language-reference/expressions/universes#level-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.

That's probably not the answer you want to hear, but there are good reasons Agda rejects this type even though the way you are using universe levels seems to be correct. In particular, if Agda would allow this then strong normalization (and hence decidability of typechecking) would be lost: in an open context with a proof of `1 <= 0`, you'd be able to exploit this datatype (or a variant thereof) to define a datatype that does not respect the universe hierarchy, which can then be used (through Girard's paradox) to define a non-terminating term. Since Agda cannot decide whether an assumption is consistent or not, it rules out these kind of user-proven level inequalities altogether and only trusts its own solver.

Comment: I guess one way of telling Agda to trust me is to just turn off the universe checker, but there's no way to tell Agda to trust me _if_ a certain condition holds. Theoretically, it should be possible to implement such a setting for Agda, if I'm not mistaken? (Not that I plan to, I'm just making sure I understand correctly.)

Comment: You can turn off the universe *locally* for a single datatype declaration using a `{-# NO_UNIVERSE_CHECK #-}` pragma (see https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1/language/universe-levels.html#pragmas-and-options). This way you can tell Agda to trust you *on that specific definition* but still check universes in other cases.